# How to set extension for a liquibase installed on CentOS?

Tags: centos, liquibase

I have liquibase installed on CentOS, but I have got very old scripts created for version 1.9, so, they need modifyColumn tag to run.

I found that there is an extension for liquibase version 3.1 and elder which can add this functionality.

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-modify-column/wiki

But I cannot figure out how to install this extension to my liquibase.
On my CetOS it is intalled as a jar file, so I cant put the extension jar to it.

When I put this jar as a set_classpath value it does not work.

Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: Is there any sort of error message? Saying "it does not work." isn't very precise.

Comment: Oh, Sorry. Yes, it is still showing "Unknow Liquibase extension: modify Column. Are you missing a jar file from yur classpath?"

I placed liquibase-modify-column-3.1.jar in liquebase-core.jar/dist/lib - still have no success...

Comment: May be the problem is that we are trying to use version 3.1... I will upgrade it to 3.2.3 and try to do everything once again

Comment: Yes, upgrade has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, upgrade to 3.2.2 has solved the problem.